# How to get access to /data/data without Root

Tags: android

I'm creating an app that I want to see the /data/data folder of android, and access the files of the apps like airbnb, WhatsApp and more, there is any way that I can do this with java?

Or its not possible to access data/data/someapp?

Comment: What you want to do with it? I mean, read it? Extract some data?...

Comment: `/data/data folder of android, ..` ? Of Android? Of your app i think. The rest is not accessable.

Comment: @Skizo-ozᴉʞS I want to extract the that and upload to firebase storage